# Which filesystem to use for a partition shared with a parallel Windows installation?

Tags: filesystems, windows, file-sharing

On my new PC I want to install both Linux and Windows, each on their own rather small partition, and put the big rest of the 1 TB HDD in a further partition (plus swap). Which filesystem should I use? My thoughts:

- NTFS. Linux has write support, but I noticed on my external HDD a huge performance drop when only a few GB (of 500 GB) were left free - suddenly a few hundred MB took half an hour to copy... Any ideas why? Also no file permissions with Linux, although that is not 100% necessary but would be a bonus
- fat32. Too old, won't support that partition size anyway
- ext3. Windows can read for example via [ext2ifs](http://www.fs-driver.org/), but what about good write support? I'd even consider a small virtual machine with a tiny Linux installation to only provide a NFS share to its host windows (probably qemu, distro recommendation are appreciated)
- ext4. I lack the experience with it...

It looks lke NTFS is the way to go for now (just as it was [two years ago](https://serverfault.com/q/3038/45248)), but I'd prefer a less proprietary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind running a VM. You could use it to share your partition via samba (simpler in Windows then NFS)

Comment: True, Samba should be easier. Can you recommend any tiny distribution with only that purpose?

Comment: @Tobias: Ubuntu's server has a vm optimized install and will offer during the installation to setup a Samba service.

Answer (score 3):

If you run [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) on Windows (through the [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) distribution or [otherwise](http://colinux.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Q2._What_Linux_distributions_run_under_coLinux.3F)), you can use it to access any filesystem that Linux supports.

Comment: +1 great idea, I already forgot I read about coLinux... can you recommend a minimum distribution for this purpose? And does this offer a mapped drive maybe without having to use samba at all?

Comment: too bad, neither supports 64 bit windows :-(

Answer (score 2):

I use an ext3 partition with ext2ifs and it works fine for reading and writing.

Comment: Does it (subjectively) perform better than NTFS on Linux?

Comment: Haven't tested it. As I first started using it, the NTFS write support in the Linux kernel was not very good, so I had no choice.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately ext2ifs doesn't seem to work with 64 bit win 7 at the moment